# LeftNavBarLibrary does not auto expand on googletv running 4.2.2

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, google-tv

I have an app that uses the auto expanding Leftnavbar found in the [Google TV samples](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_demo_samples)
The leftnav works perfectly (auto-expands / collapses on focus/loss of focus)on all v2 / v3 devices however it stays collapsed on LG TVs running v4. I tried running the LeftNavBarDemo which shows the same behavior. Any idea on how to regain the original behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to fix add an expanded check in addFocusables and focusSearch on LeftNavView to fix the problem for API >= 14

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the google widget DrawerLayout and its emulation layer via google library android.support.v4 works on all versions of GTV.